# Classes instantiated outside of the ObjectManager

Tags: magento2

What classes are instantiated outside of the `ObjectManager` so that they can't be customized in `di.xml` ?

Comment: Not 100% what you mean. Have you got one example?

Answer (score 1):

there is a list of classes that are generated outside of the ObjectManager in the following file: `vendor/magento/magento2-base/app/etc/di.xml` under `<type name="Magento\Framework\Code\Generator">`

The list is the following:

```
    <type name="Magento\Framework\Code\Generator">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="generatedEntities" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="extensionInterfaceFactory" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\Api\Code\Generator\ExtensionAttributesInterfaceFactoryGenerator</item>
                <item name="factory" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Factory</item>
                <item name="proxy" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Proxy</item>
                <item name="interceptor" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\Interception\Code\Generator\Interceptor</item>
                <item name="logger" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Profiler\Code\Generator\Logger</item>
                <item name="mapper" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\Api\Code\Generator\Mapper</item>
                <item name="persistor" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Persistor</item>
                <item name="repository" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Repository</item>
                <item name="convertor" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Code\Generator\Converter</item>
                <item name="searchResults" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\Api\Code\Generator\SearchResults</item>
                <item name="extensionInterface" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\Api\Code\Generator\ExtensionAttributesInterfaceGenerator</item>
                <item name="extension" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\Api\Code\Generator\ExtensionAttributesGenerator</item>
                <item name="remote" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\MessageQueue\Code\Generator\RemoteServiceGenerator</item>
                <item name="proxyDeferred" xsi:type="string">\Magento\Framework\Async\Code\Generator\ProxyDeferredGenerator</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
```

Comment: Not sure what makes you think these classes are not generated by the object manager? \Magento\Framework\Code\Generator::generateClass, then \Magento\Framework\Code\Generator::createGeneratorInstance, this uses the ObjectManager?

Answer (score 0):

These are classes which created before ObjectManager, on application bootstraping https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/configuration-guide/setup/initialization.html

And non Magento 3rd party classes installed via composer in vendor folder

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the instances, this may be helpful,

The instances that directly created by the keyword "new", these are wont be managed by ObjectManager,

Also the same way as set "share=false" in di XML file